# Unity trail renderer is shrinking at the end

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a skidmark system for a driving game I am working on. The way I am doing this is using a trail renderer, and enabling/disabling the emission through script(I get the same problem when I do it in the inspector though). anyway, my problem is that the trail, when it has stopped emitting seems to shrink to the center to form a triangle at the end I have no idea how to fix this and it completely ruins the effect of the skidmarks.

what I want to happen, is that is just completely cuts off and forms a straight end, where the triangle starts to form.

I have tried very many thing, like setting the min vertex distance, etc. stopping the gameObject with the renderer component from moving when not emitting isn't  working either, because when it begins moving again, the trail renderer fills the gap with another triangle.

[image: Here is a screenshot of my problem]

[image: here is a screenshot of how the trail renderer is configured]

Comment: What material are you using in the trail rendere?

Comment: @amitklein just a texture I made in photoshop(just some black rectangles) and set the shader to mobile>particles>multiply.

Answer (score 1):

Okey, the problem is that when you re-enable the `Emitting` check, the last points tend to converge.

Instead of enable/disable the `Emitting` checkbox, try to enable/disable the `TrailRenderer` component. This should do the trick.

*Edit*: The other way if you want to keep the tracks, is to decrease the `MinVertexDistance` to values like `0.001`. It will still have a little convergence, but hardly to appreciate.

Comment: I have tried to do that, however that just removes the lines completely when the car stops slipping. Any other ideas?

Comment: @WilfredReedman I've updated the answer, tell me if it helps the second approach.

Comment: it works when I am going slow perfectly, but once you pick up any decent speed(i even tried setting the distance to 0) I get the same problem...

Comment: Hmmm...edgy case, other options aren't friendly, like code your own trail renderer, or modify the trail renderer points when you enable/disable the emission. If I were you, I'll find a material/shader combination that won't be affected by the mesh (like triplanar projections) so even if your trail is triangular, the texture will be projected equally.

Comment: i haven't had much lock with any of those approaches, i have tried putting the trailrenderer on a different object the moving it only when the trail needs to be emitting, and that works fine, but when  i turn the trailrenderer back on, a trail bridges the gap i thought i had to wait for a frame or two to solve this problem but that doesn;t seem to work....

Answer (score 1):

this is how unity trails are made. Whole trail consists of quads, and last segment is always triangle, and the fun is that triangle has uv of half quad, instead of having it's own uv. It will always cause distortions unless you use solid color material.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGwJw.png)

Last segment is actually quad too, but one of it's triangles is always shrink, while second triangle perform as usual.